# How to relate tables in Mysql

Tags: mysql, relational-database

I am making a music download website. In this there are three tables named  song_tbl, artist_tbl, album_tbl.
Song_tbl
[image]

Artist_tbl
[image]

Album_tbl
[image]

Every song has an artist. But Problem is that some songs have more than one artist (example: song2 may have two artist=petersn and artist 3). Then how can i manage that. Thank you for help.

Comment: This looks like a m to n Relationship, so you'll have to create a Table Song_Artist with SongID and ArtistID as Foreign Keys.

Comment: Means i have to create fourth table Song_Artist and i do not need to delete artist_tbl ?

Comment: Yes, thats right... in Artist Table you have all Artists, in Song Tbl all Songs and in Song_Artist_Tbl only the Relations between Songs and Artists, so there you can have song 2 was sung by artist 1, next entry song 2 was sung by artist xy..

Comment: Thank you @ Mr. Patrick.  Stackover flow is very helpful website. I love it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a table song_artist_tbl that links the songs to the artists. It should have 2 columns: song_id and artist_id, and then if song 2 is linked to artists 2 and 3, you have :

```
song_artist_tbl
song_id   artist_id
2         2
2         3
```

Then you can remove the artist_id column from the song_tbl table

Comment: I also thought about this. it means in this table i will have same rows as in the song_tbl table. Am i right?

Comment: you will have probably more rows if some songs have more than one artist.

Comment: Thank you @ Mr. CCH for help me.

Answer (score 1):

remove the `artist_id` column from the `song_tbl` and add a new table called `song_artists_tbl`

```
song_artists_tbl
----------------
song_id
artist_id
```

It is called a 1-n relation.

Example data would be

```
song_id  |  artist_id
1        |  1
1        |  2
```

Comment: Thank you @ Mr. juergen d for help me.

Answer (score 1):

You use a many to many relationship with a link table.

You end up with a song_artist table that holds just the keys of the referenced tables.

Example:

song_tbl:
   song_id
   album_id
   ...

album_tbl:
   album_id
   ...

artist_tbl:
   artist_id
   ...

artist_song_tbl:
   song_id
   artist_id

With this setup, you can have a song with many artists playing it.

For further reading:
http://www.tomjewett.com/dbdesign/dbdesign.php?page=manymany.php

Comment: Thank you @ Mr. macanuga for help me.